# Wordpress-child problem with many css files in parent theme

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style

Ok, So I'm trying to setup a child theme and can't manage to solve the problem with many different css files in parent theme. When I look at [codex guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) it's just give example on how to setup it with just one style.css file in the parent theme.

The parent theme is [wooshoplite](http://dessky.com/themes-list/wooshop-lite-free-woocommerce-theme/). I got the child theme to work partial with some colors and broken images but the structure and other things looks really bad. See this attached picture.

[image: The broken wordpress-child page]

Can you guys guide and help me? What is the correct way to solve this? I've tried different ways in function.php but nothing seems tot work.

/D

Comment: Hi,
In standard setup, parent theme automatically calls all the css, you can just add the css in child which you want to override.  What exactly are the issues. please provide little more details. Thanks

Comment: Hi Vee, I have done everything the codex says but the css files from the parent theme doesn't load correctly because the child theme is ugly and look at all like the parent theme.

Comment: can you please share the URL if possible.

Comment: "...parent theme automatically calls all the css..." -- no, it does not. Where did you get this information @Vee? Are you talking specifically about "wooshoplite"?

Comment: This is going to be theme specific and will most likely be off-topic here, but if you can show the code that adds the CSS in the parent maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I saw unstyled content in a child theme when I mistakenly changed the theme name in 'style.css' while it was still selected as the active theme in Wordpress. So it wasn't picking up anything from the theme or the parent. Maybe check the names and filepaths match up?